# Sie hilft anderen Überlebenden Informationen über Familienmitglieder

Tags: phrase

> Sie hilft anderen Überlebenden Informationen über Familienmitglieder ...

I cannot understand this sentence.

Does  "Überlebenden Informationen" means the information of survivors or surviving information?

Comment: I do not think that the sentence is complete. Did you miss something at the end? Also, you you omitted capitalisation. In German that is meaningful. I would guess that *überlebenden* was capitalised.

Comment: Hello ,i just want to know what does überlebenden informationen mans

Comment: @MartinaMilad It's not complete, you need to add a second verb,  "... zu `verb`". Moreover, please, respect the capitalization. :) Überlebenden should probably be written with capital.

Comment: Ah okay thank you so much,i have just copied that sentence from a youtube video so they were already missing it

Comment: All of the things that you have omitted—capitalisation, commas, the end of the sentence—help in parsing the sentence. If you have read the sentence somewhere, then you should fix this. If you have heard it somewhere then you should add context.

Comment: Hint: *ein Überlebender* is a survivor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sentence is most probably incomplete. I suppose it is something like

> Sie hilft anderen Überlebenden, Informationen über Familienmitglieder zu bekommen.

(so, the verb in the subclause was missing)

Which would translate to

> She's helping other survivors to receive information about family members.

Comment: Or just "Sie hilft anderen Überlebenden **mit** Informationen...".